# how to trigger a django function when the user logout

Tags: django, logout

I tried to use django signals to be triggered for five different models. But, I also have the same models being used in another function and this function imports an XML file. So, it makes my page slow because of the signal.

I was wondering if I can change it to a normal function to be triggered when the user clicks in logout. How can it be done? Should I use ajax to do it or there is another way?

Comment: You could start a thread to run the expensive task when the user logs out. A more scalable solution would be to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), but only add Celery if you absolutely have to.

Comment: Thanks man for your help, but I called my function in a logout function that I created